# Relative import - from from ZSSGAN.model.ZSSGAN import ZSSGAN

Tags: python, relative-import

I'm working on the [StyleGAN-NADA repo](https://github.com/rinongal/StyleGAN-nada), and I am having issues loading the ZSSGAN function. The command line to do so is `from ZSSGAN.model.ZSSGAN import ZSSGAN`, where

1. The first `ZSSGAN` is the name of a folder
2. `model` is a folder inside the first folder
3. The second `ZSSGAN` is a script
4. The third `ZSSGAN` is a function inside the script, which defines a network architecture

If I give the command `from ZSSGAN.model.ZSSGAN import ZSSGAN` the code hangs and it never completes the task. If I cd into the ZSSGAN folder and give as a command `from model.ZSSGAN import ZSSGAN`, the task is completed in a few seconds. Unfortunately, this not a solution for me.

Is there a way I can rewrite `from ZSSGAN.model.ZSSGAN import ZSSGAN` efficiently, so that the ZSSGAN function can be loaded from outside the ZSSGAN folder?

```
ZSSGAN folder 
 |
 |
 model folder
     |
     |
     ZSSGAN script
         |
         |
         ZSSGAN function
```

The absolute path to the ZSSGAN folder is already appended to `sys.path`.

Comment: Update: I found out that there is no need to change any path and that the code in the repo doesn't need any change to run. I just had to follow what recommended here: https://github.com/rinongal/StyleGAN-nada/issues/29#issuecomment-993247202 (change op folder with the code in the StyleCLIP repo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of this repository made this ZSSGAN folder as the collection of the packages and scripts, and even their `train.py` script is inside of the ZSSGAN folder.

All their relative imports has been set up that way. But i believe you can make the ZSSGAN folder a master package by changing all relative imports in this project, like examples below:

in ZSSGAN/mapper/latent_mappers.py

```py
from mapper.stylegan2.model import EqualLinear, PixelNorm
```

in ZSSGAN/model/sg2_model.py

```py
from op import FusedLeakyReLU, fused_leaky_relu, upfirdn2d, conv2d_gradfix
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I started working in that direction and I was wondering if there was an easier solution. Thanks!